# difference between location.assign and history.pushState

Tags: javascript, html

Am I right to assume that the biggest difference between `location.assign` and `history.pushState` in terms of URL displayed in browser is that the former reloads the page and the latter doesn't? I'm ofter asked on job interviews why hashtags were needed for routing in single page applications before the HTML5 history API came into being and I guess the answer should be because the developers had no tools to change URL without page being reloaded, correct? While manipulating the `hash` part of location could be done without page reload.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you have any additional comments that I need to know?